# Getting all the tags associated with the parent object using django-taggit

Tags: python, django, django-taggit, django-tagging

I have models  `Restaurant` & [`Review`](https://github.com/bitlabstudio/django-review). `Review` has `TaggableManager()` I have no problem in making tags work for Reviews. But I also want to know all the tags that are associated with the `Restaurant` object.

I can write my own function that iterates through all reviews of the restaurant to get all the tags associated with the Restaurant. But I am looking for cleaner and easy way to get the tags that accomplishes it in a single DB query.

Comment: It will require four database queries to get what you want at minimum in my rough guess.

Comment: @AamirAdnan O(1) number of queries is okay with me. I am concerned about the number of queries it will take if the number of reviews for a given restaurant is high.

Comment: Show the models please. How is Review and Restaurant related through Tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible in a single query but this solution will take five database queries:

```
# 1 query: Get restaurant
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=pk)

# 2 query: Get content type of restaurant model
restaurant_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(restaurant)

# 3 query: Get all reviews ids for a restaurant
reviews_ids = Review.objects.filter(content_type__id=restaurant_ct.id, object_id=restaurant.id).values_list('id', flat=True)

# 4 query: Get content type of review model
review_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='review', model='review')

# 5 query: Get all tags
tags = TaggedItem.objects.filter(object_id__in=reviews_ids, content_type__id=review_ct.id)
```

But do note that the `__in` lookup on review ids might become costly on `TaggedItem`. But you wanted minimum database queries.

You can reduce one more query by fetching both content types of restaurant and review model in a single query but its not an elegant way:

```
ctypes = ContentType.objects.filter(
    app_label__in=['review', 'restaurant'],
    model__in=['review', 'restaurant']
)
assert len(ctypes) is 2
if ctypes[0].model == 'restaurant':
    restaurant_ct = ctypes[0]
    review_ct = ctypes[1]
else:
    review_ct = ctypes[0]
    restaurant_ct = ctypes[1]
```